# How to make Stripe Checkout V3 SCA ready

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm using the below script to take payments via Stripe checkout V3. I was hoping this would make my payments SCA Ready, however i'm being told my payments are still not SCA ready. Am i missing some code from the below?

```
            var stripe = Stripe('XXXX');
            var elements = stripe.elements();
            var card = elements.create('card', {
                style: style
            });
            // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
            card.mount('#card-element');
            // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
            card.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
                var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                if (event.error) {
                    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
                } else {
                    displayError.textContent = '';
                }
            });
            // Handle form submission
            var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        // Inform the user if there was an error
                        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                    } else {
                        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                    }
                });
            });
            // Send Stripe Token to Server
            function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
                // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
                // Add Stripe Token to hidden input
                var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
                hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
                hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
                form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
                // Submit form
                form.submit();
            }
```

Here is my charge code ...

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('XXXX');
  $error = '';
  $success = '';
  try {
    if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
    throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
   $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(
    array(
    'amount' => $_POST['stripeAmount'],
    'currency' => 'gbp',
    'source' => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    "receipt_email" => $_SESSION["email"],
    'description' => 'Booking - ' . $_SESSION['description'],
)
   );
```

Comment: Although you can use a Card (id: `card_*****`) with PaymentIntents, I'd recommend following https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/web

Comment: Thank you, How does the card ID work?

Comment: Normally when you tokenize a Card (saving that token to a Customer) you get a `card_***` object, which can be used as a `PaymentIntent.payment_method`

Comment: I think i see what you mean now. I need to be worrying more about the actual charge side of things, like in my amended code above.

Answer (score 1):

To be SCA compliant you need to be using the [paymentIntents API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#targetText=The%20Payment%20Intents%20API%20is,or%20redirect%2Dbased%20payment%20methods.)

Your current code suggests you are using the `charges-api`.
There is a full migration guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration).

Basically you need to replace calls from the client:

```js
stripe.createToken(card)
```

with:

```js
stripe.createPaymentMethod(
  'card',
  cardElement
)
```

and calls in the server from:

```php
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'source' => $json_obj->token_id,
    'amount' => 1099,
    'currency' => 'eur',
]);
```

to

```php
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'payment_method' => $json_obj->payment_method_id,
    'amount' => 1099,
    'currency' => 'eur',
    'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
    'confirm' => true,
]);
```

After that you need to handle possible additional actions as explained [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration#elements-step-3)

Comment: Can I have your email or is that not allowed on here?

Comment: If you have a specific question about my answer or the links I gave - you can post it here and I'll try and respond